# Hiding single column header

Tags: sharepoint-online, column-formatting

I would like to hide a single column header in a sharepoint document library list, does anyone know if there is JSON code that can do this?

I know I can custom format the overall view using:

```
{"schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json", "hideColumnHeader": true}
```

But this removes all column headers. The same code doesn't seem to work for custom formatting a single column.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my knowledge, column JSON formatting does not support customizing the column header. And we are not able to hide only one column header in view formatting.

More information:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Json column format is only working with column cell, not the column header!